# Split string by regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

I need to split a string by commas that are outside brackets. I have this string:

```
'a,b,c,d[a,b,c[a,b]],e'
```

and my split needs to return:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd[a,b,c[a,b]]', 'e']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking your first SO question! Welcome. Question. What larger problem are you trying to solve here? Are you interfacing with a system that you can't change? Sometimes when trying to parse complicated strings or syntax the answer can be to solve a different problem. For example, if your data was a valid JSON string, then you could just parse it, manipulate it as an array, and then convert it back to JSON.

Comment: Have you tryed using regular expressions?

Comment: Hi Jared, Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to return for `'a,b],c'`? Is the comma between `a` and `b` inside or outside of the brackets? Or, if it is the case that such string is outside of your consideration, then state what kind of strings are subject to your issue.

Comment: I`m working on a Middleware to pass this string in a url param and return only these keys in JSON response...

Comment: sawa, your answer worked for me, its exactly what i'm looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, my answer is not correct. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'a,b,c,d[a,b,c[a,b]],e'
.scan(/(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^,])+/)
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d[a,b,c[a,b]]", "e"]

'a,[a][b],e'
.scan(/(?:\[[^\]]*\]|[^,])+/)
# => ["a", "[a][b]", "e"]
```

Comment: this answer is much better, I just deleted mine